Is there a general solution to all spherical triangles as described by Arnold Sommerfeld?
Arnold Sommerfeld has demonstrated that it is legal to use spherical trigonometry in solving relative velocity compositions. In this work,
https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:On_the_Composition_of_Velocities_in_the_Theory_of_Relativity
he shows his solution (restricted to two right angled congruent triangles) is equivalent to the Lorentz transform.
I am looking for a solution to the general case i.e. all spherical triangles whether right angled or congruent or not.
